# What is the limit of destinations in Google Maps Distance Matrix Api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I will be using [this Google Maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) in my app.
I take user location as origin and shop locations as destinations.
Currently, I have 10 shops so it is working out well but soon I will be having more than 100. 
Is there a limit on no of values that can be passed to destinations parameter?
I could not find anything in their docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit. See the link below.

[Google Map Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits)

Comment: For people who do not want to visit the link. 
The answer is 25 for both Origins and Destinations.

Comment: It's strange but I can only call 4 destinations per request. If I raise it to 5 destionations I'm getting an error: "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API". Has anything changed here?

Comment: @Mateng, it could be because the licence you have with Google Maps is a demo one.